# Pandas Dataframe filter based on time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

From the datetime object in the dataframe I created two new columns based on month and day.

```
data["time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["datetime"])
data['month']= data['time'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
data['day']= data['time'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
```

The resultant data had the correct month and day added to the specific columns.

Then I tried to filter it based on specific day

```
data = data[data['month']=='9']
data = data[data['day']=='2']
```

This values were visible in the dataframe before filtering.

This returns an empty dataframe. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare by `9,2` like integers, without `''`:

```
data = data[(data['month']==9) & (data['day']==2)]
```

Or:

```
data = data[(data['time'].dt.month == 9) & (data['time'].dt.day == 2)]
```